# I need a Query with 2 dynamic values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have an array where i can get id's from a database table, now i need to extract those values as i run a domain link array such as: domain.com/page?id=1

Now this page will bring a category, lets say A category with ID 1 i need to list items under this category on the same database table example products, i can use it without a filter now i need a filter using arrays, here is my code, thank you in advance.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = '".$id."' DESC";
```

before this i have on my php code:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
```

So when i call from this table all comes out, but i need to filter where category 1 (example) have items, not all items with category 2, 3, 4 etc.

With my code i can get the item id as the link with array works fine for example: domain.com/page.php?id=1, but here is the catch, i get item id 1 and i need let's say category id 2, if i run the same link with id=2 i get item id 2 and that's not what i want.

I need to retrieve those values as arrays, any idea? Thank you in advance!

EDITED

Table structure example:

Items
ID, Name, Category

I need Category from Items as a filter like this: domain.com/?id=2&category=2

So i get all items under row Category only

Comment: Do you want to fetch multiple items in one query?

Comment: Do you need to send another param in the URI? For example `domain.com/page.php?id=1&category=2`?

Comment: Yes as i can get category id from items and separate items by type @AdhanTimothyYounes

Comment: That is correct @pedro but i dont know how to build this query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your URI to something like this `domain.com/page.php?id=1&category=2`

```
$category = $_GET["category"];
$query ="SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = '".$id."' AND `Category` = '".$category."'";
```

Comment: That is correct it works just fine with some tweeks thank you so much you are the best have a great day, God Bless

Answer (score 2):

Pass the query string parameter optionally

```
domain.com/page.php?id=1&category=2
```

Add the where clause dynamically like this

```
$query ="";
$conact =" where 1=1 ";
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{

   $conact.=" and id=".$_GET['id'];
}

if(isset($_GET['category']))
{

   $conact.=" and category=".$_GET['category'];
}

$query ="SELECT * FROM tablename $conact  DESC";
```

Comment: glad to help you @PedroCarvalho